# Why do we need to define a string outside the for loop before making changes to it?

Tags: python

```
def paper_doll(text):
    for i in text:
        text1=''
        text1+= i*3
    return text1

paper_doll('tom')
```

Here via this particular code I want to print every character in the string 'tom' thrice. but when I ran the code only the last character is getting printed thrice. Why is it so?

Comment: cause in each iteration `text1=' '`, so whatever changes done to it in current iteration wont affect in next iteration.

Comment: Sidenote: [the best way to create a string from a loop is `str.join()`](/a/2133580/4518341), like so: `return ''.join(c*3 for c in text)`

Answer (score 1):

On the last iteration of the loop, the program:

1. performs `text1=''` and
2. performs `text1+= i*3`.

So, regardless of what happened before the last iteration, it is erased in the first step above.

Consider moving initialization (`text1=''`) before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `text1` gets reset every time the code in the for loop runs. So it is set to `"ttt"`, then reset and set to `"ooo"`, then reset and set to `"mmm"`. Only the `"mmm"` is returned. In order to not have it reset every time the for loop runs, define it outside of the for lop instead:

```py
def paper_doll(text):
    text1=''
    for i in text:
        text1+= i*3
    return text1

paper_doll('tom')
```

Answer (score 0):

If we rewrite your code using more explicit names, it is equivalent to this:

```py
def paper_doll(text):
    for character in text:
        text1 = character * 3
    return text1

paper_doll('tom')
```

It does not give the result you want because `text1` is overwritten at every loop (therefore giving you only the last character of the string as a triplet).

What you want to do is the following:

```py
def paper_doll(text):
    text1 = ''  # define text1 outside the loop to avoid overwritting it
    for character in text:
        text1 += character * 3
    return text1

paper_doll('tom')
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers so far explain why your code does not work as expected and how to fix it. But I suppose you already knew that, since your question is "Why do we need..."

So, why? The string must already exist since you use an "augmented assignment operator", i.e. `+=`. And since it must exist and you don't want to reset it at every iteration, you need to create it outside the loop.